# Unable to get to login screen: Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, login, bootrepair

I am trying to boot my Win 10, but after the window's logo the machine stucks on the circling dots and does not reach the login window. I am unable to boot in safe mode but the command prompt is accessible. The following command produces

-bootrec.exe /rebuildbcd

-bootrec.exe /fixmbr

-bootrec.exe /fixboot

```
Access is denied.
```

Is there anything I can try to get to login screen.

Comment: The steps you tried are for cases when Windows does not even start booting. It does, so they are pointless (and harmless) in your case.

Comment: Suggested for a similar  problem here https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-hello/cant-get-to-login-screen/5deef02a-9fb8-45b2-9299-fb32754caaf8

Comment: Yeah, well, Microsoft Answer is almost entirely useless. IMHO, it’s best to not do anything mentioned there.

Comment: @drmoishe- you mean to say repair using a ISO. Yes, I think that's the only option. Kindly provide it as a answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have a recent disk image, then [reinstalling Windows from ISO](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/software-download/windows10), keeping your files, should work. Before you perform the reinstallation, *make a disk image* if there are any files that *might* be lost that you wish saved. This can be done from a boot USB, such as that created by [Macrium Reflect](https://www.macrium.com/reflectfree), [Runtime Live CD](https://www.runtime.org/data-recovery-live-cd.htm) or dd on a Linux boot drive.

This is, admittedly, a shotgun approach for a specific issue.